# invalid type: string "test@example.com", expected a sequence at line 1 column 30

Tags: python

I am trying to create a script to check if an email address is a disposable one or not using Python and Json but each time I run it am getting this error:
invalid type: string `test@example.com`, expected a sequence at line 1 column 30

I have no clue as to what next.

Here is the code:

```
import requests

surl = "https://ecxxxxxs.herokuapp.com"
payload = {"to_emails":"test@example.com"}
response = requests.post(surl, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Can't replay because I don't have `requests` installed. But did you try `data=...` instead of `json=...`? By the way, can you format your code in the post: select it and press ctrl+k.

Comment: @Ronald, thanks for your advice and suggestions. I did change to data=payload but it threw up another error of indent "expected ident at line 1 column 2"

Comment: I'm sorry, as I said, I don't have `requests` installed. But at least your post is much better readable so I'm quite sure there are others who can.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out, here is the code that worked for me.

```
import requests
surl = "https://echxxxxxs.herokuapp.com"
payload = {
    "to_emails": ["test@example.com"]
    }
response = requests.post(surl, json=payload)

print(response.text)
```